# Linux queuing system

Tags: linux, queue, clustering

We have a few computers that are used for simulations in physics which are run by a few people. I would like to install some queuing system to submit tasks and to fairly share resources. What would you recommend for single machine and for cluster? I'm interested in free solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single machine, the `at` command is probably enough. It allows you to configure your task to only run when your resource usage is low (<0.8) using the `-b` (batch) switch, or you can specify priority using the letters a-z.

example:

```
at -q b now /home/myname/script.sh
```

equivalent to:

```
batch /home/myname/script.sh
```

For clusters, use [**GNU Queue**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-queue/).

Comment: Neither at nor batch isn't good for me because it doesn't balance usage between many users, but I'll look at GNU Queue

Comment: You asked for an answer for a single machine though as well, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

In our lab, we use [PBS/Torque](https://web.archive.org/web/20111029060728/http://www.clusterresources.com/products/torque-resource-manager.php), and it works fairly well.